# in graphite server - actuator/metrics/http.server.requests count not updating

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, graphite, spring-micrometer

I have a spring boot project up and running. I have also configured dependency for `micrometer-registry-graphite` in pom file. And I have installed graphite using docker *(downloaded latest version - 1.1.6)* and it is running in **localhost:80**

When I hit the below url it properly shows the hit count.
`http://localhost:5080/api/v1/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/queue/{queueId}&tag=status:200`

Below is the response,

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": "milliseconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 29.0
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 942.520949
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0.0
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "None"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "SUCCESS"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I navigate to Graphite Browser, I'm not able to get the count value which I got previously using actuator/metrics url. [We can see the service's url `queue/queueId` is transformed to some hierarchy form].
And I can see different hierarchical structure *(attached the image)*, why it is showing under **exception, None** and other unrelated hierarchy. Can someone please explain this and I'm in need of solution to get the hit count in graphite server.

> Spring boot version: 2.2.4 RELEASE and
>   micrometer-registry-graphite version: 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrongly pointing my graphite server with `port-80` in `bootstrap.yml`. But `port-80` listening fo `nginx`, where it should point to `port-2004` which is listening for `carbon receiver`. After this change in `bootstrap.yml` I'm able to resolve this issue.